# How to swap numbers in while loop java

Tags: java, while-loop, numbers

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Swap {
  // if the number is less than 10, swap the last two numbers and print them.
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // User to enter a number between 1 and 10, but not zero.
    Scanner number = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.println("Enter a Integer(whole number) between 1 and 10. : ");
    int userNum = number.nextInt();
    while (userNum > 10 || userNum < 0) {
      System.out.println("Try again: ");
      userNum = number.nextInt();

    }
    System.out.println("Your number loop");
    while (userNum <= 10) {
      System.out.println(userNum);
      userNum++;

    }
    System.out.println("Guess the two swap numbers:");

  }

}
```

How do I swap the last two numbers? I am a beginner learning java and OOP. I have created this program where the user has to enter a number between 1 and 10. If the user enters a number below 1 and above 10, the user gets prompted to try again. Then it prints the list of numbers based off the users input. e.g. if the user enters 8, its prints the loop 8,9 and 10. I have having trouble, I understand how to swap two variable, not inside a loop. Thank you and much appreciated for your help.

Comment: So from your question what I understand is you want to swap 9 & 10 right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the maximum number is a parameter N, so that you could swap any last two numbers and place `N` before `N - 1`

```java
private static final int N = 10;
```

There are several ways to do this using different Java operators:

1. `if`, to update `delta` parameter

```java
while (userNum <= N) {
    int delta = 0;
    if (userNum >= N - 1) {
        delta = userNum == N - 1 ? 1 : -1;
    }
    System.out.println(userNum + delta);

    userNum++;
}
```

or simply skip N - 1 and print it after the loop:

```java
while (userNum <= N) {
    if (userNum != N - 1) {
        System.out.println(userNum);
    }
    userNum++;
}
System.out.println(N - 1);
```

2. `switch`

```java
while (userNum <= N) {
    int printNum = userNum++;
    switch(printNum) {
        case N: 
            printNum--; break;
        case N - 1:
            printNum++; break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(printNum);
}
```

3. two consequent loops (the second going backwards):

```java
while (userNum < N - 1) {
    System.out.println(userNum++);
}
userNum++;
while (userNum >= N - 1) {
    System.out.println(userNum--);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way this can be solved is by creating a loop(for or while) and taking the two numbers you can use the math functions- `Math.max(a,b) || Math.min(a,b)` to find the biggest and smallest numbers. Afterwards you can create more variables- c&d to save the two numbers.
goodluck

```
a=max
b=min
then
c=a
d=b;
then a=d and b=c.
```